# How to compare the means of two dependent groups when the groups are not paired?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, independence, finite-population

I have performed a behavioral experiment on bees from one single hive. I let them fly under two different conditions and now I want to compare the average flight speed in the two conditions. The number of bees are different in the two conditions. In condition 1, I have 17 bees, and in condition 2, I have 19 bees. I don't know if the same individuals were flying in both conditions, because I didn't mark the individuals. However, it is most likely that at least a few of the bees were flying in both conditions. Moreover, the same bee might have been flying more than once in each condition. Because of this, I guess I have to treat my data as dependent (repeated measures), right? Now, my question is what test I should use to see if the two group means differ from each other? Since the two groups are dependent, I can't perform an independent samples t-test, but since my data is not paired, I can't perform a paired samples t-test either...

Any kind of advice would be much appreciated!
Thank you in advance,
Therese

Edit 1: The hives are estimated to consist of about 200 bees, but I can't say for sure how many bees this hive consisted of.

Edit 2: First of all, thank you for your comments, Placidia. The two conditions were performed randomly over a couple of days, so I assume that the bees don't learn anything from the different conditions. However, I am wondering about the finite sample correction that you mentioned. In another similar experiment, I sampled 40 bees for each condition (but for each condition, I sampled the bees during two time periods, in the morning and in the afternoon, and did this over 2 days. In other words, I sampled 10 bees at a time). Do I have to make an adjustment for finite sample in that case? In yet another experiment, I sampled 17 bees from a wild population. Does that mean that the  sample is infinite, and that I don't have to adjust for a finite sample? Thank you again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I think this should be treated as two independent samples, since you cannot estimate pairwise differences. You can check normality assumption and use t-test.

Comment: Do you know how many bees are in the hive in all? I am wondering if you need to make an adjustment for finite sample. (i.e. if the total number is less than 170 bees).

Comment: I actually don't think the two samples are dependent, since the bees in the second sample are chosen randomly. Nothing in the second sample depends on the outcome of the first -- the bees don't learn anything from the first experiment, I assume. Nor are bees chosen for the second sample on the basis of what happens in the first. So I think a two-sample, unpaired, is more or less legitimate. You've got just enough bees that a finite sample correction would make no material difference. (don't know what it would be for a 2-sample test, but maybe someone does.)